# Stochastic Processes: Find the function f(n) , n = 0,1,2,... that satisfies f(0) = 0, f(n) = 1/3f(n-1) + 1/3f(n+1) +1/3f(n+2), n >= 1

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Find the function 
$$f(n),\  n \in \mathbb{N},$$ that satisfies 
$$f(0) = 0,$$

$$f(n) = \dfrac{f(n-1)}{3} + \dfrac{f(n+1)}{3} +\dfrac{f(n+2)}{3},$$ 
and
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} f(n) = 1.$$

Comment: How is this a stochastic process?  It looks like a simple recursion.

Comment: Though, what you wrote is hard to read.  Did you mean $f(n)=\frac 13\times (f(n-1)+f(n+1)+f(n+2))$?  or did you mean something else?  And I have no guess at all what you might mean by "$n≥1,\,\lim f(n),\,n\to \inf=1$".

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. I'm not sure how the n≥1 is related to the problem, I got this problem straight out of my stochastic processes textbook (Lawler, 2nd edition)

Comment: Ok.  Well, there is no apparent connection to stochastic processes here.  Nor is there enough information to solve it exactly.  You can rewrite the recursion in standard form as $f(n+2)=3f(n) -f(n-1)-f(n+1)$ or, letting $k=n+2$, as $f(k)=3f(k-2)-f(k-3)-f(k-1)$.  But you can't compute $f(1)$ from that...you'll need more initial conditions.

Comment: Maybe knowing that $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(n)=1$ suffices to pin it down exactly.  In any case, Linear Recursions with constant coefficients are a standard topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite the recursion to get the form $$f(k)=3f(k-2)-f(k-3)-f(k-1)$$

The cubic $x^3=3x-1-x^2$ has roots $1,-1\pm \sqrt 2$ so the general solution is $$f(n)=A+B(-1+\sqrt 2)^n+C(-1-\sqrt 2)^n$$

For large $n$, the $(-1-\sqrt 2)^n$ term oscillates to $\pm \infty$ and the $(-1+\sqrt 2)^n$ term goes to $0$, so the limit condition tells us that $C=0$ and $A=1$.

Finally, setting $n=0$ tells us that $0=A+B$ so $B=-1$ and the solution is $$f(n)=1-\left(-1+\sqrt 2\right)^n$$